# How to call generic methods with generic type parameter

Tags: .net, generics, ninject

Its more about generics than NInject, but I am curious.

The following **is working fine**.

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IEntityRepository<,>)).To(typeof(LoggerRepository<,>));
```

But if I want to use generics? The following **gives me compile time error**.

```
kernel.Bind<IEntityRepository<,>>().To<LoggerRepository<IEntity<>,int>();
```

or

```
kernel.Bind<IEntityRepository<,>>().To<LoggerRepository<,>();
```

I am sure I am missing something pretty simple, and must have got answered some where in ST. Can someone kindly direct me to the answer please?

**Edit:** The following **works fine**.

```
kernel.Bind<IEntityRepository<AppUser, int>>().To<EntityRepository<AppUser, int>>();
```

But I guess there should be a way without specifying the types(AppUse and int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When not all type arguments of a generic are specified, they cannot be used in any expression other than typeof(). This article could be helpful for you: [Unbound Generics: an Open and Closed Case](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexhomer/archive/2009/10/25/unbound-generics_3a00_-an-open-and-closed-case.aspx)

I'm referring to this part in particular, which discusses the use of unbound generics in conjunction with Dependency Injection:

> When you use code to perform the registration, you also omit the type parameters; for example RegisterType(typeof(MyTypes.IMyInterface<,>)). As you saw earlier, Microsoft says that "the typeof operator can operate on unbound generic types (generic types that do not yet have specific type arguments)"

**EDIT:**

Generally speaking, using unbound generics with Dependency Injection will lead to confusing and hard-to-read code. If I'm not mistaken you are trying to do it this way because of the constraints you can put on the type arguments.

But why not just define a parent interface for the types you with to use? Sure, you'll lose the constraints, but are they really necessary in a situation like this? You are already controlling the binding on one location, which is your DI container. Constraints are mainly used when your generic types are exposed through an API which others will use. Usually that code will not be wired up through a DI container by the client anyway, because they will either use derived classes, factories, or simply instantiate it directly.

Is there any particular reason why you want to do it this way?

**EDIT #2:**

Perhaps you're looking for this?

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(IRepository<>)).To(typeof(Repository<>));
```

Then, when you have `IRepository<SomeEntity>` as a constructor parameter in your calling code, ninject will resolve this for you as `Repository<SomeEntity>` at run-time.

Comment: Hi Fred, Thanks for the article, it helped me. I guess I knew this concept of the Unbound  Generics some years ago, but now its gone from my mind. And as I said kernel.Bind(typeof(IEntityRepository<,>)).To(typeof(LoggerRepository<,>)); is working perfectly fine. So I shall go with it.